# OnGenericMotionListener doesn't seem to be working

Tags: java, android

This is really weird all other listeners work like onClick etc.. but this listener doesnt seem to be working, heres my code:

```
public class HeloActivity extends Activity implements OnGenericMotionListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        View root = findViewById(R.id.root  );
        root.setOnGenericMotionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onGenericMotion(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d( "special",v.toString() ); 
        return false;
    }
}
```

why is this not working?

Comment: are you shure you do invoke "motions" on your View?

Comment: Is the listener registered with the view?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I'm currently looking at the same thing so I'll add this for future reference.

It might be because Activity implements an `onGenerericMotionEvent` method which receives motion events, but you're also implementing the method from `View` - `onGenericMotion` in the same class.

[The Android docs say to implement one or the other.](https://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/controller-input)

I've not tried how you're doing it, but I know it works by using a different class that implements `OnGenericMotionListener` and using `setOnGenericMotionListener` on the root view.

Answer (score -3):

You do realize that you both implements the listener and then attach it to the view? At the very least it is redundant....

Thank you.

Comment: In this case it's required.  Activity implements `onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event)` which you don't need to add a listener for and can just override to recieve events.  But `View` implements `onGenericMotion(View v, MotionEvent event)` and you do need to set a listener on the view.